# Converting timestamps in google big query (SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, timezone

I've returned a timestamp in google big query that looks like this: 
`2019-08-24 19:46:41 UTC`

From looking at the raw data, I know that the actual time is `2019-08-24 19:46:31 EST`, however, I think it was automatically converted to UTC since I used the `timestamp_seconds` function. I was wondering if there was a way to convert this to EST without subtracting 5 hours, since I know that in reality the time is correct, just the timezone is wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Standard SQL in BigQuery

```
DATETIME(timestamp_expression, 'Europe/Berlin')
```

Comment: That won't work because the datetime function actually converts the time to the enw timezone. I.e. if I set it to 'eastern canada' it will subtract 4 hours. The actual time is correct (i.e. it's 19:46 EST), it's just storing it as UTC instead of EST.  I don't need to convert the time, I just need to figure out how to make the time stored as EST instead of UTC. Does that make sense?

Comment: change your server settings from UTC to EST

Answer (score 0):

Just convert to a `datetime`:

```
select datetime(timestamp_expression)
```

You can now interpret this in whatever timezone you like.

I would strongly, strongly discourage you from putting anything other than UTC in a `timestamp` data type (a date/time value with a timezone offset is fine).  It represents a point-in-time, which is best represented consistently as UTC.